# Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).

Tags: calculus, limits

I came accross: $$\lim_{x \to\ 0}\frac{x\cos x - \log (1 + x)}{x^{2}}$$

I tried the following please tell me where I 'm wrong:

$$\lim_{x \to\ 0}\frac{x\cos x - \log (1 + x)}{x^{2}} $$

$$\text{(Dividing by }x)$$

$$=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to\ 0}\dfrac{ \cos x - \dfrac{\log (1 + x)}{x}}{x} $$

$$=\lim_{x \to\ 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x} $$

$$=\lim_{x \to\ 0}\frac{-2\sin^{2} \dfrac{x}{2}}{x} $$

$$=\lim_{x \to\ 0}\frac{-2x\sin^{2}\dfrac{x}{2}}{(\dfrac{x}{2})^{2}\times 4} $$
$$\lim_{x \to\ 0}\dfrac{-x}{2}=0$$
But Answer given is $\dfrac{1}{2}$

Please Help.

Comment: What did you do from the third to fourth lines?

Comment: You cannot, in general, choose to carry on the limit *of only one part of the exrpession while leaving the rest unchanged* . May I ask how did you know $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}x=1\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}x$ = $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + \dfrac{x^{3}}{3} - \cdots}{x}$ = $\lim\limits_{x\to0} 1 - \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{x^{2}}{3} \cdots = 1$ This is given in my book.

Comment: @Ayushakj Thank you. You *still cannot* take the limit **only of that expression** and leave the rest unchanged

Comment: Please consider using \log and \cos to get $\log$ and $\cos$ instead of $log$ and $cos$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The mistake is simple and somewhat common for beginners. The fact is that when you are evaluating the limit of a complex expression (i.e. consisting of many sub-expressions which are somewhat simple individually) then *in general it is not possible to replace a sub-expression by its limit in a step during overall evaluation of limit*.

Thus when you replace the sub-expression $(\log(1 + x))/x$ with its limit $1$ as $x \to 0$ you have done something wrong. This is not permitted by any of rules of limits.

However there are two situations when it is permitted to replace a sub-expression by its limit. Let $C$ be a complicated expression whose limit as $x \to a$ needs to be evaluated. And let $S$ be one of the simple sub-expressions in $C$ whose limit as $x \to a$ is already known to be $L$.

1) You can replace sub-expression $S$ by its limit $L$ if the whole expression $C$ can be written as $C = R \pm S$ where $R$ is (rest of the) expression obtained when you literally remove $S$ from $C$. I call this situation as **$S$ occurs in additive manner in the overall expression $C$**.

2) You can replace sub-expression $S$ by its limit $L$ if $L \neq 0$ and if the whole expression $C$ can be written as $C = R \times S$ or $C = R/S$ where $R$ is (rest of the) expression obtained when you literally remove $S$ from $C$. I call this situation as **$S$ occurs in multiplicative manner in the overall expression $C$. Also note that in this case $L$ must be non-zero**. If $L = 0$ then you are out of luck.

These rules are almost always used (perhaps without knowing that such rules exist) during evaluation of a limit in step by step fashion. The best part about these two rules is that the replacement of $S$ by its limit $L$ is done without knowing anything about the rest of expression $R$. **The replacements are valid irrespective of the fact that $R$ has a limit or not**.

In the current question $$C = \dfrac{\cos x - \dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x}}{x}, S = \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x}, L = 1$$ and when we remove $S$ from $C$ literally we get $$R = \frac{\cos x}{x}$$ Clearly we don't have $C = R \pm S$ or $C = R/S$ or $C = R\times S$ and hence it is not possible to replace $S$ by its limit $L = 1$.

At the same time if we write $C$ as $$C = \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{x\cos x}{\log(1 + x)} - 1}{x}$$ then we can replace the first factor by $L = 1$ and $$R = \dfrac{\dfrac{x\cos x}{\log(1 + x)} - 1}{x}$$ and it is sufficient to calculate limit of $R$ and multiply it by $L$ to get the answer. However such a split does not help us because the expression $R$ does not seem to be any simpler compared to original $C$.

---

**Note**: The rules which I have mentioned above for replacing sub-expressions by their limits are something which I have explicitly written in my blogs and many answers on MSE. I have myself not found them in any textbooks but at the same time I have seen many solved examples in various textbooks which make use of these rules implicitly. They are easy to prove and I found it worthwhile to mention them explicitly for benefit of readers so that at least they can avoid the replacements which are not valid. A more formal version of these rules along with proofs is discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2971122/72031).

Comment: I never thought about these rules in this way, I prefer indded take the limit all at once at the final step but it's a very nice pointing out!

Comment: @gimusi : for simple problems it does not matter, but for complicated expressions writing each sub-expression till the last step is clumsy and you need to write more. Replacing a sub expression early on with its limit simplifies the overall thing as well as reduces typing effort.

Comment: Can you please look into the following link (it's the same question) and tell me (maybe post an answer there) what's the error? Not sure but I think my solution does follow your way (or am I missing something?) but still here's an error. Link : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723256/322461

Comment: @Mathbg: your way is same as the one used here that's how both you and the asker here get the same expression $(\cos x - 1)/x$ after replacing $(\log(1+x))/x$ by its limit $1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, but if you note, there's a small difference in what I did. What I did was somewhat $C=R+S\times T$ and then is we say that $C-R=C'$ then $C'=S\times T$ and we can replace $T$ by its limit (going by point (2) in your answer). What's wrong here?

Comment: @Mathbg: perhaps you did not get my point. The sub-expression $T$ (based on your comment) must occur in the overall original expression $C$ (and not $C'$) in either additive or multiplicative manner.

Comment: @Mathbg: what you are suggesting will work if your goal is to find limit of $C'=C-R$ and not for $C$.

Comment: Oh oh okay, got your points. Fine, that's cool. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\neq 1$ it's undefined. And you can not directly take limit for only one part inside .

Comment: Exactly... The OP needs to use Taylor in this case

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: ...Or l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: sure... But Taylor is more insightful: you really see the asymptotical interplay between the various parts. Hopital is a great trick, but you lose the whole "growth" part

Comment: Ya but many a times it's like officially banned in case of exams

Comment: @b00nheT Thank you. I think you're right and that is why many times students are asked to try it this or that way.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Thank you. In my particular experience I've never seen such a thing. It may happen in weekly home assignments or papers, but never in exams once it has been studied. I wouldn't understand to ban in a final such a wonderful tool, either.

Comment: I personally love that method ;)

Answer (score 3):

With l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos x-\log(1+x)}{x^2}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-x\sin x-\frac1{1+x}}{2x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2\sin x-x\cos x+\frac1{(1+x)^2}}2=\frac{-0-0+1}2=\frac12$$

With Taylor series:

$$\frac{x\cos x-\log(1+x)}{x^2}=\frac1{x^2}\left(x-\frac{x^3}2+\ldots -x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3\ldots\right)=\frac12-\frac56 x+\ldots\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\frac12$$

Comment: You can reduce the second expression by extracting known simple limits to $\frac12+\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{2x}$.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$cos(x)-1=\cos(x/2)^2-\sin(x/2)^2-1=-2\sin(x/2)^2-1$$