# What is the result of $\lim_{x\to0_+} \frac{e^x - x e^x - 1}{\left(e^x - 1 \right)^2}$ without L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to0_+} \frac{e^x - x e^x - 1}{\left(e^x - 1 \right)^2}
$$
which I need to compute without L'Hôpital's rule.

(The result is $-\frac{1}{2}$ with L'Hôpital's rule).

Thanks.

Comment: Comment/hint since I don't want to take the time to write an answer: write out the power series expansions for the numerator and denominator, start the formal long division and look at the constant term.

Comment: Why are there so many questions here about limits without using l'Hopital's rule? Is that something students typically do? It's very easy to prove; and if teachers didn't want students to use it for some reason, it would make more sense to design problems where it wasn't immediately applicable.

Comment: @anomaly: if you see various limit questions and their answers on this site you will be convinced that most students simply don't have an exact idea of the hypotheses and conclusions of the theorem called "L'Hospital's Rule". And I doubt if these students really know the proof. In fact most students believe that L'Hospital's Rule is a thumb rule which says that *if plugging does not work then try differentiation and plugging and perhaps this might be needed multiple times for some problems*.

Comment: @anomaly : you may look at this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2382324/72031) which has a subtle flaw in application of L'Hospital's Rule which is difficult to detect (but easy to fix). Also see the comments where I describe the flaw.

Comment: This seems like a homework question to me.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I've actually seen a few (but only a few) such questions here where l'Hopital's rule isn't directly applicable. Those would be much better exercises to give students rather than artifically removing a simple, easily proved tool from their toolbox.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We write
$$\frac {e^x-xe^x-1}{x^2}\color {red}{\frac {x^2}{(e^x-1)^2}}. $$

Let us begin by

$$L=\lim_{0^+}\frac {e^x-xe^x-1}{x^2} $$

put $x^2=t $ and
$$f (t )=e^{\sqrt {t}}-\sqrt {t}e^{\sqrt {t}}$$

then
$$L=\lim_{0^+}\frac {f (t)-f (0)}{t} =f'(0) $$
and since
$$f'(t)=-\frac {1}{2}e^{\sqrt {t}} $$
we have

> $$f'(0)=-\frac {1}{2} $$

the $\color {red}{red }$ fraction goes to $1$.

the final result is $-\frac {1}{2} $.

Comment: Would have been better to just apply Taylor series in your second expression (whose limit is same as that of original expression as you have shown. Trying to recognize that limit as a derivative of a complicated function is not so obvious here. Moreover once you differentiate, then you have already crossed the *algebra of limits* and it does not matter whether you use differentiation for L'Hospital's Rule or to calculate Taylor series coefficients and out of all this Taylor series is the simplest.

Comment: Taylor series  is a generalization of MVT which come from derivative.

Answer (score 10):

It is also simple to look at Taylor expansions around $0$ up to at least second order
$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2... $$ then $$\frac{e^x - xe^x - 1}{(e^x-1)^2}  \approx \frac{1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x - x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x^3 - 1} {(x+ \frac{1}{2}x^2)^2} = \frac{ - \frac{1}{2}x^2  - \frac{1}{2}x^3}{x^2 + \frac{1}{4}x^4 + x^3} $$ and now by looking at the lowest order terms, the conclusion that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ follows quick

Answer (score 6):

$\lim \limits_{x \to0+}$
$\frac{e^x-xe^x-1}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{x^2}$=
$\lim \limits_{x \to0+}$
$\frac{e^x-x+x-xe^x-1}{x^2}\cdot\lim \limits_{x \to0+}$
$\frac{x^2}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}$

=
$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{e^x-x+x-xe^x-1}{x^2}\cdot\lim \limits_{x \to0+}\left[\frac{x}{\left(e^x-1\right)}\right]^2$
=$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{e^x-x-1+x-xe^x}{x^2}\cdot1$

=$\lim \limits_{x \to0+}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}-\lim \limits_{x \to0+}\frac{x\left(e^x-1\right)}{x^2}$
=$\frac{1}{2}-\lim \limits_{x \to0+}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$
=$\frac{1}{2}-1=-\frac{1}{2}$

note
$\lim \limits_{x \to0+}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$
can be proved without Lohspital rule or series

Comment: Apart from the minor $\mathrm\LaTeX $ issues (which I am fixing with minor edit) this is a very good answer and exactly the sort of answer demanded (without L'Hospital's Rule). Wonder why it was severely downvoted! +1 from my end.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Maybe because the font is a bit small? Anyway +1. It's not as "fancy" as the top-voted answer, but like you said, this is what teachers would expect basically (well, either this or Taylor expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Let's give it one more shot even though there are some good answers. We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L&=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{x}-xe^{x}-1}{(e^{x}-1)^{2}}\notag\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{e^{x}-xe^{x}-1}{x^{2}}\cdot\left(\frac{x}{e^{x}-1}\right)^{2}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{-t}+te^{-t}-1}{t^{2}}\notag\\
&=-\lim_{t\to 0^{-}}\frac{e^{t}-t-1}{t^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{e^{t}}\notag\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\text{ (via Taylor series)} \notag
\end{align}