# Why can't this limit be taken before simplification?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Assume $$f(x)=1-x^2+{x^4\over2!}-{x^6\over3!}+{x^8\over4!}+\cdots+{(-1)^nx^{2n}\over n!}.$$

I am trying to find   $$\lim_{x\to 0}{1-x^2-f(x) \over x^4}.$$

I first found $\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)}$, which is clearly just $1$, seen after plugging in $0$ for all $x$ in the expression for $f(x)$.

This leaves $\lim_{x\to0}{1-x^2-1 \over x^4}$, which simplifies to $\lim_{x\to0}{1 \over x^2}$. This limit is equal to $-\infty$, however it is not the correct answer.

To find the correct answer, one must first substitute in $f(x)$ and simplify before taking the limit.

This gives $\lim_{x\to0}{1-x^2-(1-x^2+{x^4\over2!}-{x^6\over3!}+{x^8\over4!}+\cdots+{(-1)^nx^{2n}\over n!})\over x^4}$, which can then be simplified to $\lim_{x\to0}{-{x^4\over2!}+{x^6\over3!}-{x^8\over4!} \over x^4}$, and finally $\lim_{x\to0}({{-1\over2}+{x^2\over3!}-{x^4\over4!}+\cdots})$. Plugging in zero leaves only $-{1\over2}$, which is the correct answer.

Why does the second method work while the first method doesn't? Can't limits be distributed around to all the individual $x$s? Is this due to the nature of the infinite series?

Note: This problem comes from the 2007 AP BC Calculus Exam, Free Response Question #6. This question can be found at [this link](https://secure-media.collegeboard.org/apc/_ap07_calculus_bc_sgs_final.pdf).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might be just a more confusing way of thinking about it, but that function looks like a Taylor's series expansion from somewhere. Maybe you should try and think of it that way somehow... I'm not sure exactly how though.

Comment: I believe it is actually the expansion for $e^{-x^2}$, and if I plug in 0 for x, then it is still equal to 1, which keeps the first method the same.

Comment: You can only split limits termwise when you know all the pieces exist.

Comment: Which piece doesn't necessarily exist?

Comment: All three of them.

Comment: The mistake was in not seeing that x^4/2!/x^4 evaluates to an actual  number before taking the limit.

Comment: This is a common mistake. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct, for the same reason as the thing below:

> Since $\lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$, $$
> \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x} =0
> $$

is false.

Do you notice the problem? Operations on limits tell use that, *if* $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$, $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ all exist and $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) \neq 0$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)}\,. \tag{1}
$$
Similarly, if $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ both exist, then
$$ 
 \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)+ g(x)= \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)+ \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) \tag{2}
$$

But absolutely *nothing* ever said that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{h(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)+\lim_{y\to 0}g(y)}{h(x)}
$$
! That's not a result that you can invoke nor use -- it's simply *not a result.*

Comment: Thanks. I think the specific part that I was missing was the exception when $\lim_{x \to 0}{g(x)}=0$. Since $x^4$ in the denominator does approach 0, the limit can't be distributed.

Comment: @volcanrb Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are  splitting your function, $${1-x^2-f(x) \over x^4}={1-f(x) \over x^4} -{x^2\over x^4}$$ and none of the two fractions on the right side converges.