# $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}$$

**Solution**

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}&=\\&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x^3} - \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x^3}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} -\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\\&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} -\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} -\frac{1}{x^2}\\&=0 \end{align}

But the answer is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ by L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: $\infty -\infty = ?$

Comment: edited it, $lim_{x\to 0} \space 0 = 0$

Comment: The same mistake applies regardless. You can’t break down a limit like that if the any of the individual limits are undefined/don’t exist.

Comment: But if we have $  \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-1}$, It will be indeterminate form if we put X=1 in it but we get 1 by adding them.

Comment: Please re-write your title to be *informative*.  Someone else with the *exact same problem* would never find this solution based on its title.

Comment: As an aside, recall that ⇒ is used between two statements, saying that the second statement is a logical consequence of the first statement. For instance, "5x = 10 ⇒ x = 2", because if we know that the statement "5x = 10" is true, then we can conclude that the statement "x = 2" is true. Hence, the ⇒ arrow cannot be used between mathematical things that aren't statements (such as the numbers in your example). Instead, you simply want an equals sign (=)!

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031 Your mistake starts at the first split itself as none of the terms split has a limit. The mistake of replacing $(\sin x) /x$ with $1$ is more subtle and also discussed in the linked answer.

Comment: Raghav you can see my answer once.

Comment: Is my process okay? Someone please reply.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I didn't know that. That means I've been using $\Rightarrow$ incorrectly for a long time 

Comment: @David Yes, I'll do that asap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem arises from the fact that you used $\color{red}{\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}}$, which does not have any finite defined value. In the end, you reach an indeterminate form $\color{red}{\infty-\infty}$...

Only split an initial limit into a product if the individual limits are defined.

Comment: Can't I obtain 0 by subtracting $\frac{1}{x^2}$ by $\frac{1}{x^2}$?

Comment: You can’t break down a limit into a product if the individual limits aren’t defined. That’s where your error arose.

Comment: Ohh, ok. So the the functions need to exist at the limit to be able to break down. Thank you very much man!

Comment: Exactly! (No problem.)

Comment: @Raghav - The function does not need to exist, but the limit does. If two of the three limits $\lim f, \lim g, \lim (f + g)$ are known to exist (as a finite number), then it is guaranteed that the third also exists and the relationshil $$\lim f + \lim g = \lim (f+g)$$ holds. But when only one of the limits is known to exist, there is no reason that the formula has to be true.

Comment: Is my answer okay?

Comment: Yes, it’s okay.

Answer (score 27):

This is just another way of saying what the others told you.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}
\ne \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x^3} - \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x^3}$$

The theorem is 
**IF** $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = L$ 
and $\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=M$, where $M, N \in \mathbb R$,
**THEN** $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-g(x))=L-M$

But, since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x^3} = \infty$, then the theorem does not apply.

This limit can be evaluated without resorting to L'Hospital.

\begin{align}
   \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}
   &= \frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} - \sin x}{x^3} \\
   &= \frac{\sin x - \sin x \cos x}{x^3 \cos x} \\
   &= \frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot\frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \frac{1 - \cos x}{x^2} \\
   &= \frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot\frac{\sin x}{x} 
      \cdot \frac{2\sin^2(\frac 12x)}{x^2} \\
      &= \frac{1}{\cos x} \cdot\frac{\sin x}{x} 
      \cdot \frac 12 \cdot \left(\frac{\sin \frac x2}{\frac x2}\right)^2 \\
\end{align}

which approaches $\dfrac 12$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Is my answer okay?

Comment: @Steven where did I do $\infty - \infty$

Comment: Your way is correct.

Comment: @AkashRoy Yes what you did is correct. I was looking at someone elses answer by mistake.

Comment: @steven thanks man

Comment: I didn't know we needed to go to Le Hospital to solve limits :)

Comment: @AbrahamZhang You don't. But you did read the question didn't you?

Comment: @stevengregory Check your spelling of "L'Hôpital" and then re-read my comment.

Comment: @AbrahamZhang [spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). I'm slow, but I do like a good pun.

Comment: @stevengregory Thank you, I'm dumb.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know is there later mistakes or not, but I think there's a mistake at first equation. $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0}\big( f(x) - g(x)\big)$ is not always equal to $ \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) - \lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$.

Comment: This is the most concise correct answer. The obvious example is to pick any function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$ does not exist. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\big( f(x)-f(x)\big)$ exists and equals $0$, but it is not equal to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x) + \lim\limits_{x\to 0}-f(x)$ since neither one of the latter two limits exists.

Comment: There has to be further problems with the work, as splitting works when there's a finite limit. If the OP had worked through the problem correctly, they should have found that the separate limits were indeterminate. The issue is not just splitting, but then recombining them later to cancel out the indeterminate.

Comment: Is my answer okay?

Answer (score 3):

Another way of evaluation can be the use of Taylor Maclurin Expansion of $tan x$ and $sin x$.

We have

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \tan x= \frac{x}{1} +\frac{x^{3}}{3} +\frac{2x^{5}}{15} + . . .$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x= \frac{x}{1} - \frac{x^{3}}{6} +\frac{x^{5}}{120} + . . .$$

Therefore expression turns to,

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x}{1} +\frac{x^{3}}{3} +\frac{2x^{5}}{15} + . . . -  (\frac{x}{1} - \frac{x^{3}}{6} +\frac{x^{5}}{120} + . . .)}{x^{3}}$$

Cancel the $x$ and then enforce the limit after dividing the numerator by $x^{3}$ . The expression simplifies to the calculation of sum of $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{6}$ which is $\color{red} {\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Cancel the x/1 term first and then divide the expression by $x^{3}$ then enforce the limit which is x tends to 0 .

Comment: Good solution, however I would use truncation (with big-$O$) rather than those dots. And then you don't even need the $x^5$ terms, so you can truncate at $O(x^5)$.

Comment: Ok sir Jean Claude Arbaut .  Thanks for your words.

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks @Raghav bro.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* try to take the limit of each seperately *& then* take the difference - you just get the difference between two infinities! Express $\sin$ & $\tan$ as Taylor series - each has first term in $\theta^1$ with coefficient 1, so in the difference it drops out. If you plot $\sin\theta-\tan\theta$ it looks like a cubic at the origin. Then if you divide *that* series by $\theta^3$, & you get a series with an initial term in $\theta^0$, ie a *constant* term. (This is shown in plots: if you plot that curve just described, ÷by $\theta^3$, it begins *somewhere along the **y** -axis* instead of at the origin.) This is then all that is left as $\theta\rightarrow 0$. That's equivalent to tracing the plot I have just described in parenthesis to its point of intersection with the **y** -axis.

To actually *get* the answer *immediately* you just subtract the coefficient for $\theta^3$ in the series for $\sin\theta$ from that in that for $\tan\theta$, & you get 1/3 - -1/6 = 1/2.