# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+5)\tan^{-1}(x+5)- (x+1)\tan^{-1}(x+1)$

Tags: limits

> $\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+5)\tan^{-1}(x+5)- (x+1)\tan^{-1}(x+1)$

What are the good/ clever methods to evaluate this limit?

I tried taking $\tan^{-1} (x+5) = \theta$ to avoid inverse functions but its not helpful and makes it even more complicated.

I also tried $\tan^{-1}a - \tan^{-1}b$ formula for the terms attached to x but that does not help to get rid of other terms multiplied by $1$ and $5$.

**Edit: (Please address this in your answer)**

Can't we directly do this:

$\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+5)\tan^{-1}(x+5)- (x+1)\tan^{-1}(x+1)$

$= (x+5)\dfrac{\pi}{2} - (x+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$ = \dfrac {5\pi - \pi}{2} = 2\pi$

I don't see anything wrong with it and it gives the right answer.

Is this method correct? Can it be used in other questions too?

Comment: Maybe $f-g=\frac{1/g-1/f}{1/fg}$ and use L'Hôpital Rule?

Comment: is it arctan((x+5)-(x+1))arctan...... or is it arctan(x-5)((x+1)arctan(x+1))

Comment: No, the method is incorrect: the limit cannot depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression under limit can be written as $$x\{\tan^{-1}(x+5)-\tan^{-1}(x+1)\}+\{5\tan^{-1}(x+5)-\tan^{-1}(x+1) \}$$ As you have noted in your question the second term tends to $5\pi/2-\pi/2=2\pi$. The first term on the other hand can be written as $$x\tan^{-1}\frac{4}{1+(x+1)(x+5)}=x\tan^{-1}t\text{ (say)} $$ where $t\to 0$. Noting that $(1/t)\tan^{-1}t\to 1$ we have $$x\tan^{-1}t=xt\cdot\frac {\tan^{-1}t}{t}\to 0\cdot 1=0$$ as $xt=4x/(1+(x+1)(x+5))\to 0$. Thus the desired limit is equal to $2\pi$.

---

Your approach has a serious problem as you can't replace a part of the expression with its limit in general. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031) for more details.

You can also look at it in this way. Suppose the question is modified to evaluate the limit of $$(x^2+5)\tan^{-1}(x+5)-(x^2+1)\tan^{-1}(x+1)$$ If we proceed as per your approach we again get the answer as $2\pi$. But the right answer here would be $2\pi+4$. Proceeding as I have explained above you will get $2\pi$ plus a term $x^2\tan^{-1}t$ and this will lead to $x^2t$ which tends to $4$.

Comment: But other Answers say second term cannot be taken as 2pi just like that

Comment: @Abcd: why not? You can use limit laws to do so.

Comment: @Abcd: see last paragraph of my updated answer.

Comment: @Abcd: you should carefully note the difference between your approach which is not permitted by limit laws and my handling of second term which looks similar *but* is permitted by the same laws.

Comment: Which laws??...

Comment: @Abcd: you should be familiar with limit laws which deal with limit of sum/difference /product/quotient of functions before you begin to evaluate limits.

Comment: Yes. Understood. This answer is awesome. Thanks a lot for the other example too!!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $(x+5)\tan^{-1}(x+5) - (x+1)\tan^{-1}(x+1) = \dfrac{\tan^{-1}(x+5)-\tan^{-1}(x+1)}{\frac{1}{x}}+ 5\tan^{-1}(x+5) - \tan^{-1}(x+1)$. Use L'hopitale rule on the first term and the other terms have well-known limits....

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor expansion:
$$\tan^{-1}(x+1)=\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac 1x + \frac 1{x^2} - \frac{2}{3 x^3} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right);\\
\tan^{-1}(x+5)=\frac{\pi}2 - \frac 1x + \frac5{x^2} - \frac{74}{3 x^3} + \frac{120}{x^4} + O\left(\frac 1{x^5}\right);\\
\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+5)\tan^{-1}(x+5)- (x+1)\tan^{-1}(x+1)=\\
\lim_{x\to \infty} (x+5)\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac1x+\frac{5}{x^2}+O\left(\frac 1{x^3}\right)\right]- (x+1)\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac1x+\frac{1}{x^2}+O\left(\frac 1{x^3}\right)\right]=\\
\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[2\pi-\frac 4x+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right]=2\pi.$$

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Formally, you can not evaluate it partially, because it is the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$. As a counterexample, consider $\tan^{-1}(x^2+1)$ in the second term, then the limit will be $2\pi-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
f_a(t)=\arctan\dfrac{1+at}{t}
$$
defined for $t>0$; then $\lim_{t\to0^+}f_a(t)=\pi/2$. Also, for $t>0$,
$$
f_a'(t)=-\frac{1}{t^2}\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{(1+at)^2}{t^2}}=-\frac{1}{t^2+(1+at)^2}
$$
and therefore $\lim_{t\to0^+}f_a'(t)=-1$.

With the substitution $x=1/t$, your limit can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\biggl(5f_5(t)-f_1(t)+\frac{f_5(t)-f_1(t)}{t}\biggr)
$$
With l'Hôpital and the computation above, the limit of the fraction is $0$, so the limit is
$$
\frac{5\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}=2\pi
$$

Your method is incorrect: you cannot write
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl((x+5)\arctan(x+5)- (x+1)\arctan(x+1)\bigr)
= (x+5)\dfrac{\pi}{2} - (x+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}
$$
because the limit cannot depend on $x$ and you're essentially using $\infty-\infty=0$, which is incorrect.