# What is wrong with this solution to the limits question?

Tags: limits

Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x-x^2\ln\bigg(1+\dfrac1{x}\bigg)$.

My solution:

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x-x^2\ln\bigg(1+\frac1{x}\bigg)&=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x-\frac{x\ln(1+\frac1{x})}{\frac{1}x}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x-(x\cdot 1)\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x-x\\
&=0
\end{align}

I got $0$ as answer, but the correct answer is $\frac12$.

I solved it using another method, but I just need to know why this won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure answer is 2, not 1/2?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually 1/2, I just wrote in a hurry. So why was I getting 0.

Comment: Do you know multiplication law of limit? i.e., when can you distribute limit over multiplication?

Comment: Yes, and I was trying to apply that here, but I still don't see how this won't work.

Comment: No, the multiplication law is applicable only when both limits exist and are finite. Check why this is not the case with your solution.

Comment: Try to find this limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\frac{1}{x}$ by distributing the limit.

Comment: Yeah that's infinity into 0 form.

Comment: Well my point is you can't write $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\frac{1}{x}$ as $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}$ Check this propetry and codition for [clear understanding](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html)

Comment: And please do not use images in lieu of text: they can cause problems with some displays, they are generally not searchable within the site.  Check [How do I type math in my question/answer/comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)

Comment: @Shweta, set $1/x=h$ see third problem in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%c3%b4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Replacing a sub-expression by its limit is allowed in specific cases but not in general. It is best to understand when such replacements are / are not allowed. See details in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031

Answer (score 3):

When you went from 
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x - \left( x \frac{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}{\frac{1}{x}} \right)  $$
to 
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x - \left( x \cdot 1 \right)  $$
you must have passed through an expression where "$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$" appeared.  (Otherwise, how did you replace that subexpression with its limit?)

Pretty much the only way to do that is along \begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \; & \left( x - \left( x \frac{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}{\frac{1}{x}} \right) \right)  \\
\qquad &\overset{?}{=} \left( \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \right) - \left( \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \right) \left( \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)}{\frac{1}{x}} \right)  \text{,}  \end{align*}
which is hopeless, because two of those limits do not exist.  So the equality can (and as you have found, does) fail.

Always remember, the various versions of 
$$  \lim_{\dots} {\dots} = \left( \lim_{\dots} \dots \right) [\text{operation}] \left( \lim_{\dots} \dots \right) $$
all require that the limits on the right exist for equality to be guaranteed.

Comment: By this logic, we can't take the limit inside the subtraction in the first place right, as that will encounter one term which leads to infinity and the other which is indeterminate?

Comment: Agreed.  (The indeterminate is the source of the "surprise" in this problem.)

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-x^2\log\left(1+\frac1{x}\right)\right)
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\frac{x\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}\right)\tag1\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-x\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}\right)\tag2\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}\right)\tag3\\
\end{align}
$$
Step $(1)$ is fine. Step $(2)$ is where the argument in the question goes wrong. It is not legal to simply apply a limit to a piece inside another limit. Step $(3)$ is fine and shows that step $(2)$ introduced a limit of the form $\infty\cdot0$.

Answer (score 1):

Write your term in the form
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
and use the rules of L'Hospital.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did end up using LH rule. But I don't understand why the solution I provided here won't work. Do you think you can decode that?

Comment: Since one term is of the form $\infty \times 0$, this is undetermined.

Comment: Thank you. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\left(1-x\ln(1+1/x) \right) \Rightarrow x (1-x(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{x^3}..))=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Where did the $1/n$ come from and go to? Perhaps you meant $1/x$.

Comment: OH! yes it is $1/x$.