# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{11}-3x^2+\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}$ Is this solution correct?

Tags: calculus, limits

Just want to double check whether all my operations are legal. The result seems to be correct but I want to make sure I didn't make any mistakes.
$\require{cancel}$
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{11}-3x^2+\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{11}-3x^2}{e^x - \cos x}+\frac{\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{11}-3x^2}{e^x - \cos x}+\frac{x}{e^x - \cos x}\cdot\cancelto{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{11}-3x^2+x}{e^x - 1 + 1 - \cos x}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac {1-\cos x}{x^{11} - 3x^2 + x} + \frac {e^x-1}{x^{11}-3x^2+x})^{-1}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac {1-\cos x}{x^2\cancelto{-\infty}{(x^9-3-\frac {1}{x})}} + \frac {e^x-1}{x\cancelto{1}{(x^{10}-3x+1)}})^{-1}=$$
$$ =\lim_{x \to 0} (\cancelto{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}\cdot\cancelto{0}{\frac{1}{-\infty}} + \cancelto{1}{\frac {e^x-1}{x}})^{-1}=$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac {1}{2} \cdot0+ 1)^{-1}=$$
$$=(0+1)^{-1} = 1$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You have a problem in the sixth line since you cannot directly substitute $x = 0$ into $x^9-3-\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I don't follow your second last line. How did you deal with the $1/x$ problem?

Comment: No, as it stands, your final line should be $0$ because you have the inverse of the inverse of $0$. (But the error is earlier.)

Comment: Also, you probably want to make it more explicit when you invoke the Taylor series of $\exp,\sin,\cos$. It took me a while to realise that was what you were doing.

Comment: @kingW3 exactly.

Comment: also, I didn't use taylor's series, only standard limits

Comment: $\frac1{x^2-3-\frac1 x} $ goes to $0$ but the denominator doesn't go to zero that's written wrongly. @YiFan I don't think he used the Taylor series anywhere he used the "well-known" limits $\sin x/x$, $\frac{e^x-1}x$,$\frac{1-\cos x} x^2$

Comment: @kingW3 hmm, okay I've always thought of that as a consequence of the Taylor expansion, but I do suppose it can be used independently. In either case, when invoking these limits it's good to state explicitly so that the logic is easier to follow.

Comment: @kingW3 I just made an edit to my post clarifying my reasoning. How's it look now?

Comment: Your working is needlessly complicated and has errors in certain steps. In general you can't replace a part of the expression with its limit. Such replacement can be done but only specific circumstances. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final result is correct, but in my opinion  your approach is too complicated and you should avoid the "inverse of the inverse" part. More simply, by using the same standard limits as $x\to 0$, 
$$\frac{x^{11}-3x^2+\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}=\frac{\overbrace{x^{10}-3x}^{\to 0}+\overbrace{\frac{\sin x}{x}}^{\to 1}}{\underbrace{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}_{\to 1} + \underbrace{\frac{1- \cos x}{x^2}}_{\to 1/2}\cdot\underbrace{x}_{\to 0}}\to 1.$$
If you are comfortable with the [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), there is a shorter way: as $x\to 0$,
$$\frac{x^{11}-3x^2+\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}=\frac{x^{11}-3x^2+(x+o(x))}{(1+x+o(x)) - (1-o(x))}=\frac{x+o(x)}{x+o(x)}\to 1.$$

Comment: You surely mean as $x \to 0$, right?

Comment: One more question for you: who gets pinged when you use '@user'?

Comment: Oh okay, I thought that was a new SE feature.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule also works as the limit is in the form $\frac{0}{0}$:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{x^{11}-3x^2+\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}
=\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{11x^{10}-6x+\cos x}{e^x + \sin x}
= \frac{0-0+1}{1 + 0}=1$$

Comment: Thanks for editing Robert!

Answer (score 1):

The result is correct but we can simplify some step as follows

$$\frac{x^{11}-3x^2+\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}=\frac{x^{11}-3x^2}{e^x - \cos x}+\frac{\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}$$

and since the first term tends to $0$

$$\frac{x^{11}-3x^2}{e^x - \cos x}=\frac{x^{10}-3x}{\frac{e^x - 1}x+x\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}\to 0$$

we obtain

$$\frac{\sin x}{e^x - \cos x}=\frac{\frac{\sin x}x}{\frac{e^x - 1}x+x\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}\to 1$$