# Limit existence proof

Tags: limits

Suppose I have limit
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(n)+g_1(n)\right)=k
\tag{1}
$$
And 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{g_1(n)}{g_2(n)}=1
\tag{2}
$$

Can I conclude that following limit exists
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(n)+g_2(n)\right)=k$$

If so how can i prove this?

My attempt

Add **(1)** to **(2)** and use limit sum law
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(n)+g_1(n)+\frac{g_1(n)}{g_2(n)}\right)=k+1
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(n)+\frac{g_1(n) g_2(n)}{g_2(n)}+\frac{g_1(n)}{g_2(n)}\right)=k+1
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(n)+1 g_2(n)\right)+1=k+1
$$
And finally
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(f(n)+g_2(n)\right)=k
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031) for a deep understanding of limit laws rather than trying to develop specific scenarios and guess what steps are allowed and what not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't true. Take $f(n)=n^2$, $g_1(n)=-n^2+k$, and $g_2(n)=-n^2+n$. We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)+g_1(n)=k$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g_1(n)}{g_2(n)}=1,$$ but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)+g_2(n)=\infty.$$

Your mistake lies in the second-to-last displayed equation where you take the limit of just one part of the second term... this implicitly assumes convergence of the other sequences when you don't necessarily have that convergence.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I have understood, if $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(g_1(n)-g_2(n)\right)=0$$ then it works, right?

Comment: @anatoly: if that is true, then the conclusion you asked about holds.