# Calculating $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^{\tan x} - a^{\sin x}}{\tan x - \sin x}$ without using L'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^{\tan x} - a^{\sin x}}{\tan x - \sin x}$$

*We weren't supposed to do this using L'Hospital's rule*

So in the beginning, I added and subtracted 1 from the numerator the get into a standard limit form

$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}.$$

From then on, I got a string of standard limits but it the end, the answer just doesn't seem to match. All the time I get a $0$ and the answer is $\ln(a)$.

Comment: It's unclear: were you able to get it into the form $\frac{a^x - 1}{x}$ and were unable to solve from there, or were you unable to get it into that form?

Comment: @David: If you're improving the title, why not making it actually descriptive? (And as a side note, it's either L'Hospital or L'Hôpital, but it's never L'hopital.)

Comment: Fair enough.  But it was definitely an improvement!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have :\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{a^{\tan{x}}-a^{\sin{x}}}{\tan{x}-\sin{x}}}&=\lim_{x\to 0}{a^{\sin{x}}\frac{a^{\tan{x}-\sin{x}}-1}{\tan{x}-\sin{x}}}\\ &=a^{0}\times \ln{a}\\ &=\ln{a}\end{aligned}

Because $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{a^{\tan{x}-\sin{x}}-1}{\tan{x}-\sin{x}}}=\lim\limits_{y\to 0}{\frac{a^{y}-1}{y}}=\ln{a} $ as you said.

Comment: Actually your answer should be the accepted one (+1).

Comment: This is my preferred approach. +1 Also +1 for @trancelocation.

Answer (score 1):

You are going on a right track

$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^{\tan x}-a^{\sin x}}{\tan x-\sin x}
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{(a^{\tan x}-1)\tan x}{\tan x}-\frac{(a^{\sin x}-1)\sin x}{\sin x}}{\tan x-\sin x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\ln a\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\tan x-\sin x}\\
&=\ln a
\end{align}$

Comment: I don't see how you got the middle line.  BTW my edit was to add the "$\lim_{x\to 0}$" to it.

Comment: The way you move from second expression to third expression is wrong. You can't replace a part of an expression with its limit (here $\log a$) in general. For more details see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031). The right approach is given in the answer by user CHAMSI.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{a^{\tan (x)} - a^{\sin (x)}}{\tan( x) - \sin (x)}= \frac{e^{\tan (x)\log(a)} - e^{\sin (x)\log(a)}}{\tan (x) - \sin (x)}\sim \frac{\Big[1+{\tan (x)\log(a)}\Big]- \Big[1+{\sin (x)\log(a)}\Big]}{\tan (x) - \sin (x) }$$ Simplify the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^{\tan x}-a^{\sin x}}{\tan x-\sin x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\tan x\ln a}-e^{\sin x\ln a}}{\tan x-\sin x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{\tan x\ln a}{1!}+\frac{(\tan x\ln a)^2}{2!}+\ldots\right)-\left(1+\frac{\sin x\ln a}{1!}+\frac{(\sin x\ln a)^2}{2!}+\ldots\right)}{\tan x-\sin x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{(\tan x-\sin x)\ln a}{1!}+\frac{(\tan^2 x-\sin^2 x)(\ln a)^2}{2!}+\ldots}{\tan x-\sin x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\ln a+\frac{(\tan x+\sin x)(\ln a)^2}{2}+\ldots\right)$$
$$=\ln a$$

Comment: Lopital in another way

Comment: Yes, but OP asked to solve without L'Hospital rule.

Comment: these series comes by differentiation;By the way your solution is not wrong