# Is this step in my limit evaluation correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to understand whether in the evaluation of the following limit (**without** L'Hospital),

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^{2x}=\frac1{e^2}$$

the following  step is correct:

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^{2x}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x\left(\frac1x+x\right)}{x\left(1+x\right)}\right)^{2x}
\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1\cdot\left(\color{red}{0}+x\right)}{1\cdot\left(1+x\right)}\right)^{2x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^{2x}=\cdots=\frac1{e^2}.
\end{aligned}$$
Basically in the step in the question mark, I brought in the limit operator, evaluated only the limit of $1/x$ and then brought it back out. Is this step correct? If so, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step is not allowed since we can't take the limit for a part of the expression, to obtain the result we can use that

$$\left(\frac{1+x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^{2x}=\left(\frac{1-x+x+x^2}{x+x^2}\right)^{2x}=\left[\left(1-\frac{x-1}{x+x^2}\right)^{\frac{x+x^2}{x-1}}\right]^\frac{2x(x-1)}{x+x^2}$$

Refer to the related

- [Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783782/505767)