# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x+\tan x)-2x\cos x}{x(\sin x^2)^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x+\tan x)-2x\cos x}{x(\sin x^2)^2}$$

Wolfram alpha gives $\dfrac{-7}{20}$.

Here is my work

For $x \to 0 $

$\tan x \sim x$

$\sin(x+\tan x) \sim \sin2x$

$\sin2x \sim 2x$ (I wasn't sure about this but I evaluated the limit  and got $1$.)

$\sin(x+\tan x) \sim 2x$

$\sin(x+\tan x)-2x\cos x \sim 2x(1-\cos x)$

$(1-\cos x) \sim x$

So I got that

$\dfrac{\sin(x+\tan x)-2x\cos x}{x(\sin x^2)^2} \sim \dfrac{3x}{x(\sin x^2)^2}$

which means I got $\infty$.

Did make a mistake somewhere?
And if so can this problem be solved by this approach or I need to try something else (like l'hopitals or something)?

Comment: Note that $(1-\cos x)\sim \frac {x^2}2$, not $x$.

Comment: Ok but again I got $\infty$ as limit

Comment: You aren't keeping track of enough terms.  Both the linear and the cubic terms in the numerator cancel and the (surviving) lead term has degree $5$, just like the denominator.

Comment: Since $sin(x+tanx)-2xcosx \sim 2x(1-cos x)$ I get only x^3 in the numerator.  I can't see a term that has degree 5

Comment: As @lulu commented, take more terms to see the odd powers $x^n$ with $(n \geq 5)$

Comment: There are terms of arbitrarily high order.  The fact that you discarded them does not mean that they are not there.  Worse, you seem to be discarding terms selectively.  That is, you keep some cubic terms but discard others.  Write out the first few terms in each of the relevant Taylor series.

Comment: I'm really struggling with understanding what are you trying to say. If I'm understanding you correctly (which I'm not sure I am,english isn't my native) then what you are saying makes absolutely no sense to me .If you have patience and time I would really appreciate the full answer. Anyway thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Show that $\sin(x+\tan x)=2x-x^3-\frac 4{15}x^5+O(x^7)$ and that $2x\cos(x)=2x-x^3+\frac 1{12}x^5+O(x^7)$.  Note that subtraction kills the linear and cubic terms, but the degree $5$ terms surivive.

Comment: Oh ,so I need to use taylor expansion . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up with asymptotic relations. You must be really really careful when you use them.

In this limit, we know from the denominator that we have to search for a $5$ degree expansion. Namely:
$$x\cdot(\sin(x^2))^2\,\,\sim\,\, x^5$$

Now, we set things ready for Tyalor-MacLaurin series:
$$\sin(t)=t-\frac{1}{6}t^3+\frac{1}{120}t^5+o(t^5)$$
$$\tan(t)=t+\frac{1}{3}t^3+\frac{2}{15}t^5+o(t^5)$$
$$\cos(t)=1-\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{24}t^4+o(t^4)$$

Now, we can work on t numerator:
$$\sin(x+\tan(x))-2x\cos(x)=\sin\left(2x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5+o(x^5)\right)-2x\left(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{24}x^4+o(x^4)\right)=2x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{120}x^5-\frac{1}{6}\left(2x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5+o(x^5)\right)^3+\frac{1}{120}\left(2x+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{2}{15}x^5+o(x^5)\right)^5-2x+x^3-\frac{1}{12}x^5+o(x^5)=-\frac{7}{20}x^5+o(x^5)$$

Note that, here, I haven't done all the calculations in order to exapand the $3$ and $5$ powers of quadrinomials, but I have kept only the most significant (grade $1$, $3$ and $5$).

So:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x+\tan x)-2x\cos x}{x(\sin x^2)^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{7}{20}x^5+o(x^5)}{x^5}=-\frac{7}{20}$$

Comment: Thanks, would you point to me the exact spot where I made a mistake in original question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of mistakes: first of all $\cos(x)\,\, \not \sim\,\, 1-\cos(x)$. Then: $\cos(x)\,\,\not\sim\,\, x$ when $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the asymptotic relations like $\sin  x\sim x$ in an incorrect fashion. The meaning of such relation is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x} {x} =1$$ *It does not mean that you can replace $\sin x$ with $x$ in any limit evaluation as $x\to 0$.*  I have explained this in detail [in this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031).

The simplest approach here is to use Taylor series expansions, but I usually avoid multiplication, division and composition of Taylor series. The approach below uses a little algebraic manipulation before applying Taylor series expansions.

Using L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series one can establish the following limits
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-x} {x^3}&=-\frac{1}{6}\tag{1}\\
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\tan x-x} {x^3}&=\frac{1}{3}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Replacing $x$ with $\tan x$ in $(1)$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin\tan x - \tan x} {\tan^3x}=-\frac {1}{6}$$ Multiplying this with the cube of $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x} {x} =1$$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\tan x-\tan x} {x^3}=-\frac{1}{6}$$ Adding the above to equation $(2)$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin\tan x-x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}\tag{3}$$ Let $$u=\sin\tan x-x, v=\tan x-x\tag{4}$$ and then we can rewrite the equations $(2),(3)$ as $$u/x^3\to 1/6,v/x^3\to 1/3\tag{5}$$ as $x\to 0$.

Using the identity $$\sin(\tan x+x)+\sin(\tan x-x) =2\sin\tan x\cos x$$ the numerator of the fraction under limit in question can be written as $$2u\cos x-\sin v$$ and the denominator can be replaced by $x^5$ (justify this replacement using the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin x) /x=1$). Thus we need to evaluate the limit of expression $$\frac{2u\cos x-\sin v} {x^5}$$ The above can be written as $$\frac {2u(\cos x-1)}{x^5}+\frac{2u-v}{x^5}+\frac{v-\sin v} {x^5}\tag {6}$$ The first fraction above can be written as $$\frac{2u}{x^3}\cdot \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}$$ so that it tends to $$2(1/6)(-1/2)=-1/6$$ via $(5)$ and the last fraction in $(6)$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{v-\sin v} {v^3}\cdot\left(\frac {v} {x^3}\right)^3\cdot x^4$$ which tends to $$(1/6)(1/3)^3\cdot 0^4=0$$ The middle fraction in equation $(6)$ tends to a limit, say $A$, as shown below. And therefore the desired limit is $A-(1/6)$.

The middle fraction in equation $(6)$ is $$\frac{2\sin\tan x-x-\tan x} {x^5}$$ Using the substitution $t=\tan x$ and the limit $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\arctan t} {t} =1$$ the above is reduced to $$\frac{2\sin t-t-\arctan t} {t^5}$$ and using Taylor expansions we see that it tends to $A=-11/60$. The desired limit is then $A-(1/6)=-7/20$.