# When not to use $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log\left( 1+x\right) }{x}=1 $

Tags: limits

My Teacher has told to use this as a standard result so when question is in this I directly apply this result as in this

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\log\left( 5+x\right) }{x}-\dfrac{\log\left( 5-x\right) }{x}=2/5$$
but here

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\log\left( 1+2x\right) -2{\log\left( 1+x\right)} }{x^2}=0 $$

doesn't work because solution is give using expansion of $\log\left( 1+x\right)$
I am interested to know why we cant simply multiply and divide 2x to  log(1+2x) to convert it in known form like log(1+2x) / 2x *2x yielding 2x
So what is limitation of result when to use it and when to not?

Comment: I'm completely at a loss for what you have done.

Comment: Remember that the standard limit works everywhere and it means that whenever you see $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}$ you can replace it with $1$. **It does not mean** that you can replace $\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}$ with $1$ or $\log(1+x)$ by $x$. Mathematically "$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $" is a very different beast compared to $f(x) $.

Comment: See more details at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you have the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(5+x)-\ln(5-x)}{x}.$$
Since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(\ln(5+x)-\ln(5-x))=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(x)=0$, L'Hopital's rule says that the above limit is equal to
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x+5}+\frac{1}{5-x}\right)=\frac25.$$

(I wouldn't call this a direct application of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$, but it's possible there's another solution using that fact.)

For the second problem, we again have the so-called indeterminate form $\frac00$, so applying L'Hospital's rule gives
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2}{1+2x}-\frac{2}{1+x}}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{-2x}{(1+2x)(1+x)}}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-1}{(1+2x)(1+x)}=-1.$$

Comment: i'm rather interested in application of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$

Comment: @Ha'Penny it isn't clear to me how you would directly use that fact here, but maybe it's possible. It would probably not be a very clean or easy solution though.

Comment: @Sung jin-woo 's post would be the way to do this. There's a small technicality to deal with when you replace $x$ with $2x/(5-x)$, but if this is a high school level class you probably don't need to worry about it. (Sorry if this doesn't render correctly; i'm on mobile)

Comment: @pancini Out of interest , would you please give some idea as to the technicality involved in the substitution

Answer (score 2):

Though L'Hospitals rule as used by @pancini is a better alternative to your problem, I would just show that the aforementioned 'result' can be used on both the problems.

First problem:
Rewrite as
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln\frac{5+x}{5-x}}{x}$$

The numerator is $$\ln(1+ \frac{2x}{5-x})$$

Hence the limit becomes
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+ \frac{2x}{5-x})}{(\frac{2x}{5-x})} × \frac{2}{5-x} $$

Here I use your result ,but take the expression$$\frac{2x}{5-x}$$which also tends to zero,hence your "result" is applicable modifying it as,$$ \lim \frac{2}{5-x} = \frac{2}{5} $$

In the second problem you proceed exactly as above , except at a particular step you substitute $x^2=t$
Then the standard result will show up.
I will leave that calculation to yourself.

Comment: undoubtedly this one of many methods. But I am interested to know why we cant simply multiply and divide 2x to  log(1+2x) to convert it in known form like log(1+2x) / 2x *2x yielding 2x

Comment: We can do so. In fact it is pretty much the same of what I have done in the above post ( see the line "Hence the limit becomes..." In the post.      We can't just directly do it in your second problem because of the second term in the numerator, ( which is not "compatible" with $2x$.  ) Hence it would result in an indeterminate form

Comment: In your problem , try putting the two logs together and then seperate the expression in a $\ln 1+(0)$ form and substitute $x^2=t$ and then proceed in a similar fashion as in my post.  If I still unclear, I'll edit my answer to accomodate the second solution

Comment: @Sungjin-woo Write $f(x)=\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{2x}{5-x}$. Then we know $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$. We want to conclude $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(g(x))=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)$ since in either case the thing inside $f$ is going to $0$. This is not true in general since $g(x)$ might actually be equal to $0$ at too many points. I can say more in chat if you want.

Comment: @Sungjin-woo (Also I meant to reply to your comment on my answer asking for clarification.)

Comment: @pancini thank you! You mean like those wildly oscillating function which tend to zero right

Comment: @Sungjin-woo Right; you can even have the inside function be continuous. E.g. let $f(x)=x\sin(\pi/x)$ and $g(x)=1$ for all $x\neq 0$, and set $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$. Then for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $g\circ f(1/n)=0$ but $g\circ f(\sqrt 2/n)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed result is not valid.

Having said that, you may be also interested in the power series method:
\begin{align*}
\ln(1 + x) = x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3} - \ldots
\end{align*}
whenever $|x| < 1$. If we restrict the values of $x$ to $(-1/2,1/2)$, we may claim as well that

\begin{align*}
\ln(1 + 2x) = 2x - 2x^{2} + \frac{8x^{3}}{3} - \ldots
\end{align*}

Therefore the proposed limit is given by
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + 2x) - 2\ln(1 + x)}{x^{2}} & = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x - 2x^{2} - 2x  + x^{2} + o(x^{2})}{x^{2}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x^{2} + o(x^{2})}{x^{2}} = -1
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is a highschool problem so using small o notation doesn't helps exactly