# Why is it wrong to solve the limit this way?

Tags: limits

Consider the following limit：
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^x}{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}}\\
&=e^{\lim_{x\to +\infty}(x-x^2\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right))}\\
&=e^{\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^2(\frac1x-\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right))}\\
&=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+ }\frac1{x^2}(x-\ln(1+x))}\\
&=e^{\lim_{x\to 0^+ }\frac{\frac12x^2}{x^2}}\\
&=e^{\frac12}
\end{align*}
The above solution is correct and another solution is following:
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^x}{(1+\frac1x)^{x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^x}{[(1+\frac1x)^{x}]^x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^x}\\
&=1
\end{align*}
Why is that wrong? Is that because we didn't take the limit of both the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: In the second version what you are doing is like saying $\lim_{x\to\infty}((1+\frac{1}{x})^x)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}(\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x)^x$ and then treating them independently.

Comment: You can't just replace *part* of a limit with that part's limit, and continue. You are treating the two instances of $x$ as independent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is not possible in general but allowed in some cases.

Comment: The first is not entirely precise either. The second to last equation should be accompanied by the observation that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x−\ln(1+x)−x^2}{x^2}=0$ and that $e^x$ is injective. If you look carefully, just stating that equality is exactly the same as the step in the second two last equation in the second argument. So, both are fallacious arguments. The only difference is that in the first one can filly in the gap in the argument.

Comment: @user Sure, but you have to explain *why,* and usually explaining why you can so is some work, usually quite a bit of work, not just mere assertion.

Comment: Yeah, it should really be $x-\log(1+x)=\frac{1}2x^2+o(x^2).$

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed, in general, take the limit for a single part of the entire expression.

Notably, in this case you have made this mistake twice in two different ways using that

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(h(x))}$$

and then

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(h(x)) =g(\lim_{x\to +\infty}h(x))$$

For a general discussion refer to:

- [Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783782/505767)

and other [similar examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1783782?sort=newest).

---

For the solution we can avoid Taylor's series or l'Hospital as follows

$$\frac{e^x}{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}} = e^{-\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)-x}{\frac1{x^2}}} \to e^{-\frac12}$$

using the method presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1337564/505767).

Answer (score 3):

(I've colored equals signs below as red when the argument is falty. Apologies to the color-blind.)

You've done this:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)^x}\color{red}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{(\lim_{y\to\infty} g(y))^x}$$

If you could do that kind of substitution, you could solve a lot of problems this way:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\color{red}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\lim_{y\to\infty} 1+\frac 1y\right)^x=\lim_x 1^x=1.$$

---

The real question is why you'd think you could let one tiny part of the limit go to infinity first.

One way to see this is wrong is to compute:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)^x}{(\lim_{y\to\infty} g(y))^x}$$

In your technique, this limit is $1.$

If $L=\lim_{y\to\infty} g(y),$ then let $h(x)=g(x)-L.$ $h(x)$ is the "error."

Since $g(x)=L+h(x),$ we can compute the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x)^x}{L^x}=\lim\left(\frac{g(x)}{L}\right)^x=\lim\left (1+\frac{h(x)}{L}\right)^x.$$

All we really know is that $h(x)\to 0.$ So, for example, if $h(x)=\frac 1x,$ then the right side of the limit would be $e^{1/L}.$

In your case, you need an estimate for $h(x)=e-(1+1/x)^x.$ I'm not sure how to do that, but I'd bet, from the actual answer, that $h(x)=\frac{e}{2x}+o\left(\frac1x\right).$

---

Another way to see the error is to take the first approach, but apply the second answer's logic. We'll just take the logarithms. Your second logic is:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-x^2\log(1+1/x))\color{red}=\lim_{x\to\infty} x-x\left(\lim_{y\to\infty} y\log(1+1/y)\right)=0.$$
since $y\log(1+1/y)\to 1.$

As you can see here, the common factor of $x$ is the problem. It is true that $1-x\log(1+1/x)\to 0,$ but it is not true that $x(1-x\log(1+1/x))\to 0.$