# Where is the flaw in my calculation of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

The limit at 0 may be correctly calculated this way:
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2(1+\cos(x))}{\sin^2(x)}=\\\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\cdot(1+\cos(x)\right)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x \to 0}(1+\cos(x)=1\cdot2=2
$$

Where is the flaw in the following?
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{1-\cos(x)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\,x$$

Thank you.

Comment: The first factor, $x/(1-\cos(x))$ diverges.  You can only separate limits if both factors converge.

Comment: Regarding $\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {x}{1-\cos x}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0} x\right)$ one limit is heading toward infinity and the other is heading to zero.

Comment: $0\times\infty$ is [indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms).

Comment: Thank you all. _______

Comment: An easier example is $\lim_{x\to0}(x\times\frac 1x)$ which can't be seprated.

Answer (score 3):

This step

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\cdot(1+\cos(x)\right)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\left(1+\cos(x)\right)$$

is allowed because both limits exist finite, but here

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{1-\cos(x)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x$$

as noticed in the comments, the first limit diverges while the second one is equal to zero (i.e. it is an indeterminate form $\infty \cdot 0$), therefore the step is not allowed, as dicussed in detail in the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/505767).

Comment: @Why You are welcome, refer to the linked answer for a more general discussion for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late response and this may not be the intended method but you can also use l'Hôpital's rule twice for this:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{1-\cos(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2}{\cos(x)}=2$$