# Rules for calculating limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

Sorry for the vague title, I feel like I cannot explain it properly with such few words, so I'll try here:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left( \frac{x\arctan{(1/x)}}{\sin{3x}} \right) = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left( \frac{x\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{3x}} \right)$$

Would evaluating first $\arctan({1/x})$ and then use L'hopital's rule be allowed? Or would I have to use L'hopital's rule first before evaluating any factor? I still seem to get the right answer though, which is $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: What you're using is an application of the following rule: the limit of a product is the product of limits. Do you see how that applies here?

Comment: The rule mentioned by @Sambo is true only if all the limits exist and are finite

Comment: @Sambo I fear I don't...

The trouble I have is I don't know if I am allowed to evaluate specific factors inside the limit without having to replace all x's with the 0's, in my case. What I did in my post was simplifying by specifically evaluating the inverse tan, and then continuing, by using L'hopital's rule. Comparing to websites such as symbolab, they do not do this. They use L'hopital's rule without first simplifying arctan.

Comment: @Andrei: the rule works in an appropriate sense (the one required here) if just one of the limits is known to be finite and non-zero: if $g(x) \to a \in \Bbb{R}$ as $x \to x_0$ and $a \neq 0$, then $f(x)g(x)$ has a finite limit $b$, say, as $x \to x_0$ iff $f(x)$ has a finite limit, $c$ say. And, if so, we will have $b = ca$.

Comment: @Sambo On second thought, I do get it! What I did, inadvertedly, was split them into two different limits, x/sin3x and arctan (1/x), and then first evaluating arctan, and then evaluating the other limit, using L'hopital's rule. It makes sense!

Comment: What you did is correct. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1783818/72031) for more details.

Comment: @FreezeAim That's exactly right! Congrats on figuring it out yourself. If you want, you can post an answer to your own question.